# Create Dynamic Button from Sql

Tags: c#, sql

I saved my button properties into my database. When i open my form i want to create a button with this properties.
I'm trying something like that. But i dont have results.
Should i use something else instead of that?

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from button_properties", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
Button dynamicButton = new Button();

dynamicButton.Height = (read["height"].ToString());
dynamicButton.Width = (read["width"].ToString());
dynamicButton.Text = (read["text"].ToString());
dynamicButton.Name = (read["name"].ToString());
dynamicButton.Location = new Point(20, 150);

Controls.Add(dynamicButton);

read.Close();
```

Comment: "i dont have results"  What does that mean?

Comment: It doesnt Create anything

Comment: To mark a question as solved, click the green checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your question. Putting “Solved” in the title does not mark the question as solved in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `.Read()` at least once when using a DataReader, also things like `SqlDataReader` and `SqlConnection` should really be inside a using statement.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from button_properties", con);
con.Open();
using(SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(read.Read())
    {
        Button dynamicButton = new Button();

        dynamicButton.Height = (int)read["height"];
        dynamicButton.Width = (int)read["width"];
        dynamicButton.Text = read["text"].ToString();
        dynamicButton.Name = read["name"].ToString();
        dynamicButton.Location = new Point(20, 150);

        Controls.Add(dynamicButton);
    }
}
```

Now the code will add a button per row in `button_properties`.

Comment: Thank you sir. But in height and width says Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Thank you Sir i solved it. I just use Convert.ToInt32 and it worked! My only question is how will i do this work with location im trying this:                          dynamicButton.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(read["location"].ToString()));

Comment: Are all your numbers stored as strings in your database? Instead of doing `.ToString()` it might be better to cast it as a int `dynamicButton.Height = (int)read["height"]`. For the point, points are two ints so you likely need to store two columns in your database for x and y and just read those. `dynamicButton.Location = new Point((int)read["location_x"], (int)read["location_y"]));`