# dynamic buttons in wpf from sql server

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

i am new to WPF

i have a table product in sql server and i want to create dynamic buttons in a grid or stack panel that have the product name and price as a content and the product id hidden.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YDqC.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Dynamic Button from Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968072/create-dynamic-button-from-sql)

Comment: in that code there's something called controls. add it has an error in my code what is meant by controls?